# Etherchannel physical port SPAN mirror

Tags: cisco, switch, etherchannel, mirror

We have 4x1G `Etherchannel` on trunk and for troubleshooting i want to monitor one of its physical port.

Can i monitor using `SPAN` port `mirror` and configure its physical port for source SPAN?

```
Group: 99
----------
        Port-channels in the group:
        ---------------------------

Port-channel: Po99    (Primary Aggregator)

------------

Age of the Port-channel   = 8d:08h:08m:05s
Logical slot/port   = 12/99          Number of ports = 4
HotStandBy port = null
Port state          = Port-channel Ag-Inuse
Protocol            =   LACP
Port security       = Disabled

Ports in the Port-channel:

Index   Load   Port     EC state        No of bits
------+------+------+------------------+-----------
  0     00     Gi2/0/1  Active             0
  0     00     Gi2/0/2  Active             0
  0     00     Gi2/0/3  Active             0
  0     00     Gi2/0/4  Active             0

Time since last port bundled:    8d:08h:07m:53s    Gi2/0/4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is what I've found:

Can You Configure SPAN on an EtherChannel Port?

An EtherChannel does not form if one of the ports in the bundle is a SPAN destination port. If you try to configure SPAN in this situation, the switch tells you:
        Channel port cannot be a Monitor Destination Port 
        Failed to configure span feature 
        You can use a port in an EtherChannel bundle as a SPAN source port.

Source:
http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/switches/catalyst-6500-series-switches/10570-41.html#anc63

Comment: i read that doc and its confusing that is why i post question. So answer is `YES` can i configure as a source????

Comment: Yes. You can do it as a source port.